# Any way to configure what signature version a Minio server accepts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, aws-sdk, minio

I have a Minio server set up and everything appears to be running normally.

For my CLI, I have this in my config.json:

```
    "myalias": {
        "url": "https://myurl",
        "accessKey": "myaccesskey",
        "secretKey": "mysecretkey",
        "api": "S3v4",
        "lookup": "auto",
        "Region": "us-east-1"
    }
```

But when I try to upload a file, I get this:

```
# mc cp test.txt myalias/stuff/
 0 B / 19 B [                                                       ]  0.00% 
mc: <ERROR> Failed to copy `test.txt`. The request signature we 
calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and 
signing method.
```

If I change my api in config.json to this:

```
"api": "S3v2"
```

It works:

```
# mc cp test.txt myalias/stuff/
test.txt:    19 B / 19 B [==============================] 100.00% 193 B/s 0s
```

My question is, can I configure Minio to use version 4 signature verification instead of version 2? Isn't minio supposed to use version 4 by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with NGINX that our IT guys had set up. The problem and solution are outlined in these links:

https://github.com/minio/minio/issues/5298

https://docs.minio.io/docs/setup-nginx-proxy-with-minio

tl;dr:

After hours of research, I realized that I missed the Host directive on both reverse proxy configurations I had set.

For completeness, I missed those ones:

Nginx

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://minio;
}
```

Caddyfile

```
proxy / localhost:9898 {
      transparent
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the version of your minio and mc? Minio should support both s3v4 and s3v2. Also is there anything different about your access key and secret key?

Answer (score 1):

This might be stupid, but I ran into exactly this error and it turned out that my secret key was simply wrong.

I forgot that I did not use my default password here but rather the one configured as `MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD` for the docker container.

Comment: In my case, I put quotes around the password in the docker compose environment but the quotes needed to be typed when logging in, or more simply removed from the compose